# Creating an array of student names and scores in Visual Basic that updates a list box with the information

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project that has multiple forms. The main form has a listBox that displays the contents of a tab delimited text file. The text file looks like this:

`Bowser, William C   84  98  77  83  75  92
Smithson, Anne K    76  87  65
Brewer, Juliette    23
Oblonski, Walter H  88  97  86  75  93  98
Smith, John D   86  75  84  93  91  78 
Katinga, Raphael P  56  87  44  32  22
Robertson, Gerald T 67  78  87  93  87  75
Smith, John B   89  67  75  84  92  83`

The assignment is as follows:

> StudentScores
>
> Develop an application that reads in student names (limited to 20
>   students) and scores (up to 6 per student) from a tab delimited file,
>   StudentScores.txt (in Student Files). The application shall allow the
>   user to add students to the student set, add and change scores for a
>   student in the student set, delete a student and the student’s scores
>   from the student set, and save the student set back to the
>   StudentScores.txt file.

I am not having any luck getting it to correctly add a new student & scores or save the current "updated" information. I think I am not using my arrays correctly.
below is my code for the main form (frmStudentScores) and a second form (frmAddNewStudent)

My frmStudentScores code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class frmStudentScores

    ' frmStudentScores top level declarations
    Dim ScoreTotal As Integer = 0
    Dim ScoreCount As Integer = 0
    Dim ScoreAverage As Integer = 0

    ' Executing the program shall cause reading of the StudentScores.txt file and display.
    Private Sub frmStudentScores_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Set the title bar to date and time
        Me.Text = "StudentScores Scores - " & DateTime.Now 'String.Format("{0:d}", currentDate)

        ' Read the file into parallel string arrays 
        Dim AllLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(filePath_Read)
        Dim Columns(20) As String

        ' Parsing file lines into columns
        For LineIndex As Int32 = 0 To intFileLineCount
            Columns = AllLines(LineIndex).Split(vbTab)
            S_NAME(LineIndex) = Columns(0)
            S_SCORE1(LineIndex) = Columns(1)
            S_SCORE2(LineIndex) = Columns(2)
            S_SCORE3(LineIndex) = Columns(3)
            S_SCORE4(LineIndex) = Columns(4)
            S_SCORE5(LineIndex) = Columns(5)
            S_SCORE6(LineIndex) = Columns(6)

        Next

        ' Display the data in a ListBox;
        Dim Row As String = 0

        For LineIndex As Int32 = 0 To intFileLineCount

            Row = String.Format("{0,-30}{1,5}{2,5}{3,5}{4,5}{5,5}{6,5}", _
                            S_NAME(LineIndex), _
                            S_SCORE1(LineIndex), _
                            S_SCORE2(LineIndex), _
                            S_SCORE3(LineIndex), _
                            S_SCORE4(LineIndex), _
                            S_SCORE5(LineIndex), _
                            S_SCORE6(LineIndex))

            lstBxOutput.Items.Add(Row)

        Next

        ' Calculates the total score, how many scores and average score of the selected student.
        If lstBxOutput.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            ' Make the currently selected item the top item in the ListBox.

            For Index As Int32 = 1 To 6

                If Columns(Index) <> " " And Columns(Index) <> Nothing Then

                    ScoreTotal = ScoreTotal + Val(Columns(Index))
                    ScoreCount = ScoreCount + 1
                    ScoreAverage = ScoreTotal / ScoreCount

                End If

            Next
        End If

        txtBxScoreTotal.Text = ScoreTotal
        txtBxScoreCount.Text = ScoreCount
        txtBxAverage.Text = ScoreAverage

    End Sub

'**********************************    On List Box Selection Change   **********************************************
'@===============================================================================@'
'@  To display the total, count, and average for a student, the user selects the @'
'@  student from the list box. If the list box is empty, the total, count, and   @'
'@  average labels should be cleared                                             @'
'@===============================================================================@'
Private Sub lstBxOutput_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)Handles lstBxOutput.SelectedIndexChanged

    'Change Score Total, Score Count and Average to reflect the new data selected
    Dim Colum(7) As String

    'Colum(0) = S_NAME(lstBxOutput.SelectedIndex)
    Colum(1) = S_SCORE1(lstBxOutput.SelectedIndex)
    Colum(2) = S_SCORE2(lstBxOutput.SelectedIndex)
    Colum(3) = S_SCORE3(lstBxOutput.SelectedIndex)
    Colum(4) = S_SCORE4(lstBxOutput.SelectedIndex)
    Colum(5) = S_SCORE5(lstBxOutput.SelectedIndex)
    Colum(6) = S_SCORE6(lstBxOutput.SelectedIndex)

    'For loop checks to see if is a value in Colum(Index) and if there is, it calculates 
    'the Total Score, How many scores have been entered and the average of the entered scores.
    For Index As Int32 = 1 To 6

        If Colum(Index) <> " " And Colum(Index) <> Nothing Then

            ScoreTotal = ScoreTotal + Val(Colum(Index))
            ScoreCount = ScoreCount + 1
            ScoreAverage = ScoreTotal / ScoreCount

        End If

    Next
    'Display the Total Score, How many scores have been entered and the average of 
    'the entered scores in the appropriate text boxes
    txtBxScoreTotal.Text = ScoreTotal
    txtBxScoreCount.Text = ScoreCount
    txtBxAverage.Text = ScoreAverage
    ' Reset the ScoreTotal, ScoreCount and ScoreAverage to zero
    ScoreAverage = 0
    ScoreTotal = 0
    ScoreCount = 0
    ScoreAverage = 0

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click

    'To add a new student, the user clicks the Add button to display the Add New Student dialog box.
    frmAddNewStudent.Show()
    Me.Hide()

End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    'To update an existing student’s scores, the user selects the student in the list box and 
    'clicks the Update button to display the Update Student Scores dialog box.
    frmUpdateScore.Show()
    Me.Hide()

End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    'To delete a student, the user selects the student in the list box and clicks the Delete button.
End Sub

Private Sub btnReport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReport.Click
    'To display a formatted report listing the student names, their scores, their averages, and 
    'their grade, the user selects the Report button. Report design is left to the 
    'COP 1332 student, however, it shall be columnar formatted.
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    'The Save button may be pressed at any time. This shall cause overwriting of the 
    'StudentScores.txt file contents with the current contents of the student set from 
    'that stored in the program.

    ' Save to filePath_Write
    Dim myStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(filePath_Write)

    ' Prepare File content...
    For LineIndex As Int32 = 0 To lstBxOutput.Items.Count '- 1
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}{0}{5}{0}{6}{0}{7}", _
              vbTab, _
              S_NAME(LineIndex), _
              S_SCORE1(LineIndex), _
              S_SCORE2(LineIndex), _
              S_SCORE3(LineIndex), _
              S_SCORE4(LineIndex), _
              S_SCORE5(LineIndex), _
              S_SCORE6(LineIndex)))
    Next

    myStreamWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}{0}{5}{0}{6}{0}{7}", _
              vbTab, _
              S_NAME(intFileLineCount), _
              S_SCORE1(intFileLineCount), _
              S_SCORE2(intFileLineCount), _
              S_SCORE3(intFileLineCount), _
              S_SCORE4(intFileLineCount), _
              S_SCORE5(intFileLineCount), _
              S_SCORE6(intFileLineCount)))

    'For i = 0 To lstBxOutput.Items.Count - 1
    '    myStreamWriter.WriteLine(lstBxOutput.Items.Item(i))
    'Next

    myStreamWriter.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

    'exit the program
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

The code for form frmAddNewStudent (used to add a new student) is:

```
Public Class frmAddNewStudent

    ' frmAddNewStudent top level vars
    Dim int_Counter As Integer = 0

    ' adds a user entered value to the txtBxScores.Text string
    Private Sub btnAddScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddScore.Click

        ' adds the value to array SelectedScoreVals()
        SelectedScoreVals(int_Counter) = txtBxScore.Text

        txtBxScores.Text = txtBxScores.Text + " " + txtBxScore.Text
        txtBxScore.Text = Nothing
        txtBxScore.Focus()

        int_Counter += 1

    End Sub

    ' adds a row to frmStudentScores.lstBxOutput
    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click

        If txtBxName.Text = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Name")
            txtBxName.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If


        S_NAME(intFileLineCount + 1) = txtBxName.Text
        S_SCORE1(intFileLineCount + 1) = SelectedScoreVals(0)
        S_SCORE2(intFileLineCount + 1) = SelectedScoreVals(1)
        S_SCORE3(intFileLineCount + 1) = SelectedScoreVals(2)
        S_SCORE4(intFileLineCount + 1) = SelectedScoreVals(3)
        S_SCORE5(intFileLineCount + 1) = SelectedScoreVals(4)
        S_SCORE6(intFileLineCount + 1) = SelectedScoreVals(5)

        MessageBox.Show("The listBox Index is: " + frmStudentScores.lstBxOutput.SelectedIndex.ToString + "    " + _
                               "The scores for the selected Index are:  " + _
                               SelectedScoreVals(0).ToString + "  " + _
                               SelectedScoreVals(0).ToString + "  " + _
                               SelectedScoreVals(0).ToString + "  " + _
                               SelectedScoreVals(0).ToString + "  " + _
                               SelectedScoreVals(0).ToString + "  " + _
                               SelectedScoreVals(0).ToString)


        Dim Row As String = Nothing

        Row = String.Format("{0,-30}{1,5}{2,5}{3,5}{4,5}{5,5}{6,5}", _
                              S_NAME(intFileLineCount), _
                              S_SCORE1(intFileLineCount), _
                              S_SCORE2(intFileLineCount), _
                              S_SCORE3(intFileLineCount), _
                              S_SCORE4(intFileLineCount), _
                              S_SCORE5(intFileLineCount), _
                              S_SCORE6(intFileLineCount))


        frmStudentScores.lstBxOutput.Items.Add(Row)

        ' Clean up and close
        Array.Clear(SelectedScoreVals, 0, 6)
        frmStudentScores.Show()
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClearScores_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearScores.Click

        txtBxScores.Text = ""
        int_Counter = 0

    End Sub

    ' Returns you to frmStudentScores
    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click

        frmStudentScores.Show()
        Me.Close()

    End Sub
```

Also I have a Module with the name and scores arrays in it:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Module mdlGlobals

    ' Sets the directory paths to variables
    Dim dirPath As String = "C:\Users\dehnb\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VBFinal\StudentScores\"
    Public filePath_Read As String = dirPath & "StudentScores.txt"
    Public filePath_Write As String = dirPath & "StudentScoresWright.txt"

    ' Declare parallel string arrays 
    Public S_NAME(20) As String
    Public S_SCORE1(20) As String
    Public S_SCORE2(20) As String
    Public S_SCORE3(20) As String
    Public S_SCORE4(20) As String
    Public S_SCORE5(20) As String
    Public S_SCORE6(20) As String

    'Public aryStudentData()() As String = New String(6)() { _
    '                      S_NAME, _
    '                      S_SCORE1, _
    '                      S_SCORE2, _
    '                      S_SCORE3, _
    '                      S_SCORE4, _
    '                      S_SCORE5, _
    '                      S_SCORE6}


    Dim AllLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(filePath_Read)

    Public SelectedScoreVals(6) As String
    Public intFileLineCount As Integer = File.ReadAllLines(filePath_Read).Length - 1

End Module
```

Comment: Parallel arrays are a horrible choice for this type of task

Comment: Thats what I was told but the assignment specifically ask for parallel arrays. How would you advise me to do it if I were not using the parallel arrays? I am more interested in making it work than I am about using parallel arrays.

Comment: Ask your teacher if this would be acceptable in the work place, the answer would be no. There is a place for arrays and this is not it. Some day schools are going to have to step up and change there stupid curriculum.

Comment: Arrays need to be `ReDim` before adding, all arrays must be dimension-ed the same if they are to be used by the same index.

Comment: Do you think a Jagged Array would work better here?

Comment: No, a custom class and a `List(Of thisCustomClass)` for the collection.

Comment: [List(Of T) class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of a custom class:

```
Public Class Student
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Grades As New List(Of Integer)
  Public Function AverageGrade() As Double
    Return Grades.Average()
  End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Private Students As New List(Of Student)
...
'in some event where you add students
Students.Add(New Student With {.Name = "Bob", .Grades = New List(Of Integer) From {97, 99, 86}})
```

Get a students average grade(lambda expression):

```
Dim studentBob = Students.Where(Function(s) s.Name = "Bob").First.AverageGrade()
```